# Inverse sort in table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got function which render table rows with gradual `id`.How to inverse it? (first row with `id=n`, last with 1)

**thats my code**

```
renderRows = () => {
    const { receipts } = this.props
    const rows = receipts.map((receipt, index) => (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>{receipt.id}</td>
        <td >{receipt.organization.name}</td>
        <td>{receipt.receiptNumber}</td>
        <td>{receipt.series}</td>
        <td>{receipt.customer.fname}</td>
        <td>{receipt.customer.lname}</td>
        <td>{receipt.customer.patronymic}</td>
        <td>{receipt.customer.phone}</td>
        <td>
          {receipt.priceList.map((priceListEntry, index) =>
            <div key={index}>
              {priceListEntry.service.name}
            </div>
          )}
        </td>
     </tr>);
   return (rows);
 }
```

Comment: Try to use `sort()` or `reverse()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `javascript` `sort` function : **[DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)**

```
renderRows = () => {
    let receipts = this.props.receipts
    receipts.sort(function(a,b){ return b.id - a.id})
    const rows = receipts.map((receipt, index) => (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>{receipt.id}</td>
        <td >{receipt.organization.name}</td>
        <td>{receipt.receiptNumber}</td>
        <td>{receipt.series}</td>
        <td>{receipt.customer.fname}</td>
        <td>{receipt.customer.lname}</td>
        <td>{receipt.customer.patronymic}</td>
        <td>{receipt.customer.phone}</td>
        <td>
          {receipt.priceList.map((priceListEntry, index) =>
            <div key={index}>
              {priceListEntry.service.name}
            </div>
          )}
        </td>
     </tr>);
   return (rows);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `const rows = receipts.reverse().map(/*[...]*/)`

[Reverse Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

You can also use the [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function to create the exact order you need. (here: `const rows = receipts.sort((a,b) => { return b.id - a.id}).map(/*[...]*/)`)

Comment: This means that the IDs are already sorted, you can't be really sure about that

Comment: Yep, I added the sort function to handle the case

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#Sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/sort) based on the `receipts` IDs.

```
renderRows = () => {
    const { receipts } = this.props
    receipts.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id);
    const rows = receipts.map((receipt, index) => (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>{receipt.id}</td>
        <td >{receipt.organization.name}</td>
        <td>{receipt.receiptNumber}</td>
        <td>{receipt.series}</td>
        <td>{receipt.customer.fname}</td>
        <td>{receipt.customer.lname}</td>
        <td>{receipt.customer.patronymic}</td>
        <td>{receipt.customer.phone}</td>
        <td>
          {receipt.priceList.map((priceListEntry, index) =>
            <div key={index}>
              {priceListEntry.service.name}
            </div>
          )}
        </td>
     </tr>);
   return (rows);
 }
```